# What is a good SQL Server strategy for copy/move database tables between two location in different networks?

Tags: sql-server

What would be the best strategy for a SQL server database copy/move from a source location separated by the Internet to a destination? (preferably automated)
The destination will **not** need to alter data but will require query access.

- In this case both locations are not connected by VPN.
- They are on different domains/networks.
- The frequency of getting the copy from the source will be approximately twice a month.
- Assuming both sites are using MS SQL Server 2008 (not Express/Standard editions).
- Can include strategy with differential backups if suitable
- Prefer to use a MS SQL Server solution rather than custom programmatic solution
- Initial Database size and the incremental changes might be approximately ~150MB

Possible solutions I can think of:
**Snapshot Replication with FTP** - the only problem is trying to Automate the FTP connection in retrieval. Also provides flexibility with Articles that can be chosen. But the tables require Primary Keys (PK)
**Log Shipping (Recovery in Standby mode)** - the problem here is copying and retrieving the Transaction Logs from the folder; as they are on different networks.

Comment: If using Replication with FTP you and using Windows Server 2008 you may want to enable Stateful FTP command: netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable

Answer (score 0):

For a single 30MB database twice a month, I would use an SSIS package which can handle either backup/restores or dumping /reading tables and the associated FTP

The fact of no direct connection limits your options immensely (replication, log shipping, mirroring etc)

Comment: I have since found the size to be more at ~150MB at about twice a month. The SSIS package would be do-able except that we would prefer to keep it automated which is why Replication is looking good. Except that I am unsure how well it will handle on ADSL2+ with ~1MB upload speed over VPN. Not sure how automated SSIS can be made. Also to reduce work load of the Publisher in this case, having to run a SSIS package.